# Getting address of object pointed by reference

Tags: c++

I'd like to enforce that an object should exist before passing it to a function:

```
void Class::setStoredObject(MustExist& obj) {
  stored_object = &obj;
}

// Lifetime of ptr is my responsibility
std::unique_ptr<MustExist> ptr = std::make_unique<MustExist>();
classObject.setStoredObject(*ptr);
```

anyway I also need to store that object (big one) by reference or address so I usually grab a pointer to it.

Is this safe to do? I.e. getting the address of a reference to refer to the original pointed-to object.

Alternatively, any other/better way that I could achieve this?

Comment: Obviously the lifetime of the object must exceed that of any dereferencings of the pointer.

Comment: I use the same method. Pointer and reference are quit similar, important differences: pointer can be uninitialized or null, can be incremented, reference not

Comment: @KerrekSB yes, that is my responsibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with this, per se. Of course, if the original object goes out of scope and gets destroyed, the saved pointer to the object will no longer be valid.

Comment: So it's confirmed that I'm getting the address of the original object, not of a "stack-parameter reference for the function" right?

Comment: @Dean you're getting the address of whatever object you supplied as function parameter. If you post the actual code you call the function with then this would be clearer

Comment: @M.M Edited. Thanks.

Comment: @Dean: Perhaps your uncertainty comes from this: expressions work in terms of *values*, not variables. Values are never references. You take the address of a value, not of a variable. The value resulting from evaluating the name of a reference variable is the value that was bound to the reference.

Comment: ok, in the updated code `stored_ptr` will point to the object which was being managed by the `unique_ptr` at the time of the call. You must take care not to release `ptr` before changing `stored_ptr` to no longer point to that object. Also this somewhat goes against the semantics of `unique_ptr` .

Answer (score 1):

The safest way to ensure that you get an existing object and that it won't be deleted without a possibility to check this, is by instantiating and passing a shared_ptr.  This way you can choose to store the shared_ptr so you're sure it won't disappear (but then you need some clean up code) or store as weak_ptr so you can only use it when it still exists.

Storing raw pointers of objects controlled by smart pointers can lead to very subtle issues, that are difficult to trace back to code.

Comment: Of course, if the real question is whether getting the address of a reference gives the same address as the referenced object, then the answer is 'yes'.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is not a good design to get and to use a raw pointer out of **std::unique_ptr** as it breaks all the idea of it.

Comment: Using it in functions is not a problem: not all functions must be aware which smart pointer controls the object, but storing the pointer or using it in threads can lead to object life time issues (dangling pointers)

Answer (score 0):

Dereferencing `ptr` and passing the object by reference is not a good semantic for what you are trying to do.

If the caller context needs the `unique_ptr` you should use:

```
void Class::setStoredObject(std::unique_ptr<MustExist> obj_ptr)
```

and do the call

```
classObject.setStoredObject(std::move(ptr));
```

expressing the fact that the calling context is giving away ownership.

Otherwise you can give up the unique_ptr altogether (its existence is not justified in your example). In this case I would consider either of:

```
void Class::setStoredObject(const MustExist& obj) // ok for copy
void Class::setStoredObject(MustExist&& obj) // move semantics, expressing the fact that the caller is done using the object.
```